# How to use set.intersection in an if-statement?

Tags: python, string, if-statement, set, intersection

I want to check if multiple strings are within a larger string called "str_a". The following is what I currently have and it works.

```
animals = {"giraffe", "tiger"}
str_a = "A giraffe is taller than a tiger."

if "giraffe" in str_a or "tiger" in f:
    print ("T")
else:
    print ("F")
```

However, I wanted to represent the if-statement in a more concise manner and I think set.intersection can help me achieve that. I tried the following with set.intersection and it prints out "F" instead of "T" - I'm not sure why. Any guidance on this would be appreciated!

```
animals = {"giraffe", "tiger"}
str_a = "A giraffe is taller than a tiger."
matches = animals.intersection(str_a)

if matches:
    print ("T")
else:
    print ("F")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn a string into a set of words, use `.split()`:

```
>>> set(str_a.split())
{'giraffe', 'A', 'taller', 'tiger.', 'is', 'than', 'a'}
```

You can now do a set intersection:

```
>>> set(str_a.split())&animals
{'giraffe'}
```

Note that `'tiger.'` is not the same as `'tiger'`. To strip punctuation, you can use a set comprehension:

```
>>> {w.rstrip(',.:') for w in str_a.split()}
{'giraffe', 'tiger', 'A', 'taller', 'is', 'than', 'a'}
```

Then both will be found:

```
>>> {w.rstrip(',.:') for w in str_a.split()}&animals
{'giraffe', 'tiger'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use `any`:

```
s = set(str_a.split())
if any(animal in s for animal in animals):
    print('T')
else:
    print('F'
```

Comment: note this will include partial matches, like if word like `girafette` is in `str_a` for example

Comment: And `'tiger'` will match `'tigerlilly'` and `'not a tiger'`

Comment: You're right guys. The answer from dawg is much better. It should be marked as accepted. @Kareena

Answer (score 0):

You could use the isdisjoint method of your animals set. `isdisjoint` will tell you if all elements of `animals` are absent from the words in `str_a` (essentially the "F" result) without creating a second set.

```
animals = {"giraffe", "tiger"}
str_a = "A giraffe is taller than a tiger."

if not animals.isdisjoint(str_a.split()):
    print("T")
else:
    print("F")
```